# google oauth for mobile web application

Tags: web-applications, oauth, mobile-website

Am using oauth in a mobile web application.

When user clicks on sign in with google. It shows a google account login page which is not a mobile webpage. I checked in blackberry, nokia e63, samsung monte(I have no idea what OS it has), nokia 5233, iphone4..

Only iphone4 shows a mobile sign in page.. other's just show the desktop sign in page which takes some time to load.. also user need to scroll to right to see the username and password box and to type in their information.. Blackberry had some issues in redirecting the page back to my web application.

All the functionality works fine.. except google shows the desktop version of their account sign in page. How do I make google to show mobile sign in page.